# Button to Save Excel range of cells (not manually selected, but automatically detected) as ".csv" with same name as original ".xls" file

Tags: vba, excel, csv

Here you have some information regarding my Excel file so you know better my worksheet layout:

- it is a normal excel sheet (.xlsx) which starts at row 5 and has many different entries for a table.
- Some of this entries are automatically calculated from a function which uses values from cells from the same row.
- The document goal is to be a template, so the number of rows containing information may vary depending who is using the template.
- Even though the number of rows containing information may vary the functions have to be present at all cells in a column, so whenever someone places a new entry to the table it is automatically calculated.
- The formulas are all of them like this: " = if (  *#cellvalue <> ""#*  ;  *#dosomething#*  ;  *#""#*) ", which mainly places an empty string if no value is present in a cell, and does someting else if a value is entered.
- The template will be cell protected, so only some cells would be able to be modified.

During the last days I've been trying to implement a Button for excel which does the following things on click:

- Detect which rows contain table entries, but discarting the rows which contain no manually entered values and may only contain the function stated on the previous paragraph. The table always start at raw 5 but might end at row 50 or 60 or whenever the person who uses it stops to manually enter new entries to the table. It is possible that only the row 5 contains information, but it can never happen that any entry is present in the table.
- Create a new ".csv" file, containing only the previously selected rows, on the same folder as the ".xlsx" file which is being used as a template. The ".csv" file name must be the same as the ".xlsx" file, but appending some information present in some specific cells (for example information present in cell A1, B1, A3, C3). The information to be appended will always be string text which will never come from a function output but from manually entered by the keypad. It could be that some of this cells contain no information (empty strings such as: "").
- The button action should directly save the file in the same directory where the template is without opening a dialog to save the file. The button should also prompt a dialog in case the name being used for the ".csv" file already exists as a "filename.csv" file in the same folder. This prompted dialog should ask if you would like to overwrite the existing file with the same name with the new one.

Comment: That is a tall order, check out this site on range selection codes and other ideas.
[Selection Codes](http://www.xlorate.com/selection-codes.html)

Comment: I appreciate the amount of work you put into this question, it might be best to upload a sample file somewhere and then attach a link to the file. Basically, supply something for somebody to work with. I usually use my Google Drive Account to upload attachments.

Comment: Ok ... And what exactly is your problem. You should raise a job offer if you search for someone who implements that for you. Otherwise show us what you already have and where you struggle

Answer (score 0):

Written without Excel on my current PC so you'll need to tinker a bit but something like this:

```
' Rows that contain entries:

' assuming data is in column A (i.e. col 1)
Dim rowHolderArray() as long
Dim lastRow as long

lastRow = range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
Redim rowHolderArray(lastRow)

For x = 1 to lastRow

   If cells(x,1) <> "" then rowHolderArray(x) = x

next x
```

2) to populate the csv, create it using the AddWorkbook method then do something like:

```
Dim rowCounter as long

rowCounter = 1

For x = 0 to UBound(rowHolderArray) - 1

   If rowHolderArray(x) <> "" then 
      cells(rowCounter, 1) = rowHolderArray(x)
      rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
   End if

Next x
```

3) To save the book use Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/" & yourWorkBook.name & ".xlsx"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone, finally I could implement what I wanted. Here you have my example code so you can check it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Boolean
Dim j As Integer
Dim currentworkbook As String
Dim currentpath As String
Dim csvfilename As String
Dim contentrange As Range
Dim researchername As String
Dim projectname As String
Dim aditional_info As String
Dim year As String
Dim month As String
Dim day As String
Dim hour As String
Dim minute As String
Dim WB As Workbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' Calculate which was the last row with information
i = True
j = 12
While i
    j = j + 1
    If (Application.Cells(j, 2) = "") Then
        i = False
        j = j - 1
    End If
Wend

' Copy the information I wanted to save in a .csv file
Application.Range(Application.Cells(12, 1), Application.Cells(j, 16)).Copy


' Create some variables to manage the path ant some filenames
currentworkbook = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 5)
currentpath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
csvfilename = currentworkbook & "_"
researchername = Application.Cells(1, 2)
projectname = Application.Cells(3, 2)
aditional_info = Application.Cells(5, 2)
year = Format(Now(), "yy")
month = Format(Now(), "MM")
day = Format(Now(), "dd")
hour = Format(Now(), "Hh")
minute = Format(Now(), "Nn")

' Create a new workbook which will be filled with the information copied and then saved as a .csv file.
Set WB = Workbooks.Add
With WB
    .Title = "mytitle"
    .Subject = "Mysubject"
    .Sheets(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    .SaveAs currentpath & "\" & csvfilename & "_" & year & "-" & month & "-" & day & "_" & hour & "h" & minute & "m_" & projectname & "_" & researchername & "_" & aditional_info, xlCSV
    .Close
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```